# JFrame: navigate to another frame using JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to navigate with buttons in Java Swing.
I want to go to another existing frame when i click on a button.
I will attach first the Menu Panel:

```
public class MenuPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel l1,l2;
    JButton btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;

    MenuPanel()
    {
        setVisible(true);  
        setSize(600, 300);  
        setLayout(null);  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        setTitle("Menu Panel For Final Project");  
        l1 = new JLabel("Menu Panel Bitches: ");
        l2 = new JLabel("This Program Made By Ghetto K");
        l1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28));
        l2.setForeground(Color.RED);
        l2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC,22));
        btn1 = new JButton("Add Child");
        btn2 = new JButton("Add Worker");
        btn3 = new JButton("Add Class");
        btn4 = new JButton("Add Task");
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);
        l1.setBounds(150, 30, 400, 30);
        l2.setBounds(150, 80, 400, 30);
        btn1.setBounds(0, 230, 120, 30);
        btn2.setBounds(160, 230, 120, 30);  
        btn3.setBounds(465, 230, 120, 30);  
        btn4.setBounds(320, 230, 120, 30);
        
        
        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
        add(btn3);
        add(btn4);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MenuPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btn1)
        {
            
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn2)
        {
            
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==btn3)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

I want to navigate to this panel:

```
public class AddWorkerPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    JLabel l1, l2, l3;
    JTextField tf1, tf2;
    JButton btn1, btn2;
 
    AddWorkerPanel()
    {
        setVisible(true);  
        setSize(600, 300);  
        setLayout(null);  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        setTitle("Add Worker form in Java");  
        l1 = new JLabel("Add Worker Form - Type Details Below:");  
        l1.setForeground(Color.blue);  
        l1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));  
        l2 = new JLabel("Worker-Name:");  
        l3 = new JLabel("Worker-Class-Number:");   
        tf1 = new JTextField();  
        tf2 = new JTextField();  
        btn1 = new JButton("Submit");  
        btn2 = new JButton("Clear");  
        btn1.addActionListener(this);  
        btn2.addActionListener(this);  
        l1.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);  
        l2.setBounds(80, 70, 200, 30);  
        l3.setBounds(80, 110, 200, 30);  
        tf1.setBounds(300, 70, 200, 30);  
        tf2.setBounds(300, 110, 200, 30);  
        btn1.setBounds(80, 230, 200, 30);
        btn2.setBounds(300, 230, 200, 30);  
        
        add(l1);  
        add(l2);  
        add(tf1);  
        add(l3);  
        add(tf2);   
        add(btn1);  
        add(btn2); 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddWorkerPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Minimize your code

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding ..

Comment: .. and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

A `JFrame` is the actual frame that sits on the screen. So what you want to do is derive your `MenuPanel` and `AddWorkerPanel` classes from `JPanel`, so that they can both sit inside of one frame. Then, in your main frame class, you can have a `CardLayout` holding both of your panels, and have a button that cycles through the cards on the card layout, using the `next()` method in the card layout instance that you have stored.

Comment: Great answer. But while the OP should be using panels rather than frames, there is no need or case here to extend anything. The code should just be using plain 'out of the box' instances of both `JFrame` and `JPanel`.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to close one JFrame and then open the other you should be avble by just simply doing this in the calling method of your button:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new AddWorkerPanel();
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually not that simple, not using `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`..